# Intellij/Gradle - Can't see Jar in classpath although it exists in module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

when running my app in intellij I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

while when running it via `gradle run` task there is no such error.

when checking if any `slf4j` jar (which is not a direct dependency from my `build.gradle`) appears in the classpath intellij runs, it doesn't,

but it **does** appear in the External dependencies tree:

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the jar is in the module dependencies? And if so, is it set to compile?

Answer (score 1):

As Rafi said, need to go to Project Structure, find the module that's being run, go to Dependencies tab and set to compile. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to the intelliJ project classpath. Normally this can be easily done by clicking on the red bulb on the editor or by adding it manually in the project settings